# Using find in map with user defined class as key

Tags: c++

I have define a class Entry with 2 integer values a and b, and a vector of Entry 'e'. Now, I am going to define a map' m' of Entry and int where int is number of time that entry appear in vector. The thing is find function is considering Entry(1,2),Entry(1,12) and Entry(1,13) as one. Two entries should be same when both a and b are equal. But here if only a is equal its considering the two entries as same.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Entry{
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        Entry(int,int);
        bool operator <(Entry);
        bool operator >(Entry);
        bool operator ==(Entry);
};
Entry::Entry(int x,int y):a(x),b(y){
}
bool Entry::operator ==(Entry e){
    if(a==e.a && b==e.b)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool Entry:: operator <(Entry e){
    if(a<e.a)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
bool Entry:: operator >(Entry e){
    if(a>e.a)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int main(){
    map<Entry,int> m;
    vector<Entry> e;
    e.push_back(Entry(1,2));
    e.push_back(Entry(10,21));
    e.push_back(Entry(1,13));
    e.push_back(Entry(1,2));
    e.push_back(Entry(1,12));
    for(int i=0;i<e.size();i++){
        if(m.find(e[i])==m.end())
            m[e[i]]=1;
        else{
            m[e[i]]=m[e[i]]+1;cout<<e[i].a<<" "<<e[i].b<<" "<<m[e[i]]<<endl;

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: 1) In your operators, pass the value by `const reference`, not by value: `bool Entry::operator==(const Entry& e);`.  2) All you need is to define `operator==` and `operator <`.  The other operators such as `operator >` should be written in terms of these operators.  For example `>` is the same as `not (equal or less than)`. 3) You should return `true` or `false` for functions that return `bool`, not 1 and 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map` is using the relational operator `<` for ordering and checking key uniqueness. Since your implementations of `operator<` use the `a` member only for comparing it will ignore `b` when evaluating key equality. `operator==` is not used from the map interface - it is replaced by `!(a < b || b < a)`. You need something like

```
bool Entry::operator<(const Entry& e){
    return a < e.a || a == e.a && b < e.b;
}
```

You could remove `operator>` and `operator==` or keep them if you need them for other purposes.

Comment: "std::map is using the relational operators < and > for..." - it just uses `operator<` (`y < x` can be used to test `x > y`, and if neither `x < y` nor `y < x` then they're equal).  Good code would be `return a < e.a || a == e.a && b < e.b;`